# C# execute code after application.run()

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem similar to this one: [How can I execute code after my form starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100428/how-can-i-execute-code-after-my-form-starts)

But the solution there won't work for me because I am not running a form, I'm running a single custom control, which is a tray icon that monitors things. (Similar to the Icon Dropbox has, where that is the only interface the user has with the program)

What should I do to run code when the control is created? (which has to be after the message pump starts)

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to understand/answer if you posted the code that you have currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [**`Application.Idle`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event.

> Occurs when the application finishes
>   processing and is about to enter the
>   idle state.

E.g.

```
Application.Idle += delegate { Console.WriteLine(Application.MessageLoop); };

// Output: true 
Application.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for. I'll just need to make sure it only runs the first time its called and it will be perfect. I guess I'll just remove that delegate when I'm done.

Comment: This will be called a myriad times, not once.

Comment: @John: You can always unsubscribe from the event from within the handler to make it one-shot.

Comment: @Ani okay, you should add that into your answer code 
Anyone who reads this question and answer is likely totally new to C-Sharp, so unsubscribing from a Idle event is not the first thing that comes into a newbies mind.

Answer (score 4):

First option would be to post a windows message to yourself. That way it will not be dispatched until your thread starts pumping messages. A second option is to hook into the Application.Idle event which is fired when the message queue is empty. Your third option would be to set and run a Timer for a small duration and hook into the Tick event for when it expires. Fourth and the last for now is to fire a delegate asynchronously as they use the message queue as the mechanism for being fired.