# finally block not executing after Application.Run(new main_form)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, interop, try-finally

I wanted to have some code execute before my program exited, so I thought that editing to the VS created Program.cs to look like:

```
...
try
{
    Application.Run(new main_form);
}
finally
{
    special_shutdown_code();
}
...
```

would do the trick, but my `special_shutdown_code()` is not being executed when I click the [x] in the upper right corner of the main form.  I went back and added print statements:

```
...
try
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("Before");
    Application.Run(new main_form);
    System.Console.WriteLine("After");
}
finally
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("finally");
    special_shutdown_code();
}
System.Console.WriteLine("post-finally");
...
```

"Before" was the only output printed.

From what I've read the Application.Run functions should return.  I'm at a lost.  Any explanations would be appreciated.

This is a C++/CLR + C# + C mixed program, but the main part is C#.

I'm hoping to get an explanation for what is not happening rather than suggestions for how to accomplish the same functionality.  I am able to work around this for most cases, but what seemed like the cleanest, easiest to understand, and the right way to do it not working at all confuses me.

Comment: How are you closing it? there are some pretty brutal ways to kill an app if you try...

Comment: So I take it that "After" isn't printed either? And how do you close this program?

Comment: I closed the window with the X in the upper right corner of the title bar.  I know that exceptions aren't the magical tools that most programming books want us to believe they are, but I expected that this would have been good enough for most cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I execute code after my form starts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100428/how-can-i-execute-code-after-my-form-starts)  Really good description of why is in the answers.

Comment: @ChrisLively: This is not a duplicate of that question.  That question seems to be about executing some code while the form is up or opening.  My question is about after a form closes; particularly for exceptions.  Putting a `finally` block in a `Load` event handler doesn't make sense, and since the application could fail to actually open the form using a `Closing` handler for the main form won't handle many of the death paths that I think could be handled.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Form mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.Closing += delegate(...)
{

};
Application.Run(mainForm);
```

Not sure if this would actually work...

Comment: Would that run when an unhandled exception occurs? I think not.

Comment: @Jason: I appreciate the suggestion, but I was actually looking for an explanation for the program behaving the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the answer while looking into running message pumps on threads without a main form.

There are 3 versions of `Application.Run()`.  I've found very little good information on using the version that takes no arguments.  The one I see the most is `Application.Run(Form)`, which I believe ends up calling `Application.Run(new ApplicationContext(Form))` possibly after doing some setup.  This sets the `ApplicationContext.MainForm