# c# Visual Studio not showing debug string

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# but I feel like this should output "hi":

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PathMet_Controller
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            Debug.WriteLine("hi");            
        }      
    }
}
```

My output window gives me this:

[image]

In playing around, it did output "hi" once, but it would only output after I stop running the file.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4100473) in particular (though you should find all of them useful)

Answer (score 1):

Because `Application.Run` will start special loop which will end when you exit your win forms application.

If you want to print something at start, use events provided by `Form` class.